# Python how to update dict without overwriting other values

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have this:

```
config = {
    "a": {
        "hello": 1,
        "goodbye": 2,
    }
}
```

and I want to update `["a"]["hello"]` to 10 like this:

```
update = {
    "a": {
        "hello": 10
    }
}

config.update(update)
```

at this point config is now:

```
config = {
    "a": {
        "hello": 10
    }
}
```

How can I update one dict with another dict without overwriting other values/subdicts?

Comment: why not just `config['a']['hello'] = 10`?

Answer (score 2):

```
config = {
    "a": {
        "hello": 1,
        "goodbye": 2,
    }
}
```

You can do:

```
config['a']['hello'] = 10
```

The updated `config`:

```
config = {
    "a": {
        "hello": 10,
        "goodbye": 2,
    }
}
```